# get two cells to print from same page

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if its possible to have a macro that populates a page and prints it then goes to the next one from the column and so on.

The number would go on Sheet2, C2 and name on C4. this is a template so it should delete empty and then refresh the next number and name from the list in sheet1.

The only thing is could it be set so I can select the starting cell or does it have to print all in the row at once? Say I only wanted to print 20 today then another 50 tomorrow can that be done....

Its a lot of manual typing at the moment so any help would be great.

I have an example below (names changed) that the column could have up to 500 names that need to be printed to place in each folder. Below put the number in correctly I just cant work out how to also include the name from cell D2 in sheet1

```
Sub PrintLoop()
    Dim c As Range, LR As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LR = Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In Sheets("sheet1").Range("C2:C" & LR)
        Sheets("sheet2").Range("C2").Value = c.Value
        Sheets("sheet2").PrintPreview
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You'd need to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve but yes this is possible. You can set the PrintArea to be a single cell or a range of cells.

Comment: ok specific. I have numbers in C2:c10 small example and names in D2:D10. So when the print page pulls the cell C2 to sheet2 i want the name also to populate related to the number.

Answer (score 0):

Select just the rows you want to print before running...

```
Sub PrintLoop()

    Dim rw As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each rw In Selection.Rows
        With Sheets("sheet2")
            .Range("C2").Value = rw.EntireRow.Cells(3).Value
            .Range("C4").Value = rw.EntireRow.Cells(4).Value
            .PrintPreview
            '.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1
        End With
    Next rw

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim,Thanks for the reply. It took me a while to see that i need to select the range, but i like this due to being able to select the rows of data i need rather than all in the column. Cheers and thank you. It works great cheers Marty P.S  after send message i only noticed your 1st line above the code :) cheers.